# Matlab - Using part of a filename from an existing file to name a new file

Tags: matlab, filenames

I have the following problem in Matlab.
I'm opening an existing file with this line:

```
fileID = fopen(filename,'r');
```

I then create a new file with this line:

```
fid=fopen('output.txt','w');
```

That works just fine. The problem is, I don't want it to be called "output". I would like to call it using the original filename and adding a bit of string to it, like this: "filename_new.txt". The output file also has to be a .txt file, regardless of what the original one was.
I know I can get the name of the original file into string using this:

```
[pathstr, name, ext] = fileparts(filename)
```

but I have no idea where to go from there.
So to sum it up, the new file should be called "name_new.txt".
I have a feeling this is either trivial to you guys or you're gonna tell me it's not actually possible this way. Either way, I'd be grateful for any help.

Comment: Using  your `fileparts` function, I'd suggest just `outName = [name '_new.txt']`  `fid=fopen(outName,'w')`  This would handle file types  other than just 3 letter extensions.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this:

```
filename_out = [filename(1:end-4),'_new.txt'];  
fid=fopen(filename_out,'w');
```

`filename(1:end-4)` is a quick and easy way to remove the `.txt` ending. If you know that it'll all be txt-files, this should suffice.
With the `[]` you can combine the two strings, in this case appending a `_new.txt`

Answer (score 1):

http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/fullfile.html

Try then

`f = fullfile(pathstr, strcat(name,'_new.',ext))`

Answer (score 0):

```
%% Rename whole *copy.png -> .png  by JYJ

root_dir = '/Users/Yoojeong/Desktop/stims/png';

%retrieve the name of the files only
listdir = dir(fullfile(root_dir, '*.png'));

% i = 1; 
    for i = 1:length(listdir)
[pathname, filename, extention] = fileparts(listdir(i).name);

%the new name 
newFilename = [filename(1:end-5),'.png'];
movefile(fullfile(root_dir, listdir(i).name), fullfile(root_dir,newFilename))
    end
```

Comment: Surrounding your answer by some explanatory text would improve it.